# Permission problems on a mounted volume with Apache

Tags: apache, macos, osx-snow-leopard

So, I have a Mac Snow Leopard server (Server A) and I've been using a self-built Apache for it, but it's been acting up lately and I want to use the built in. But since this is a production server, I want to test it out first, mounting the appropriate directories on my second server (Server B) and testing it.

So I mount the "/Atlas" directory (my entire CMS) of Server A on Server B with this command:

```
mount_hfs afp://username:password@server_a/Atlas /Atlas
```

After having manually created the /Atlas directory.

Now, when pointing a virtual host to have DOCUMENT_ROOT at "/Atlas/Sites/sandman/" (which is the correct path for that site on Server A) and surfing to the site, Apache reports a 403 (Access forbidden) and says it can't read the file ("You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.")

Now, the files are owned by user "sandman" on both machines, and Apache on Server A is run by user "sandman", but on the built in Apache on Server B it is owned by user "_www" with UID 70. The files are readable by "world" so user _www SHOULD be able to read them just fine.

Anyone knows what the problem may be? I was hoping that I could perhaps store the CMS files on Server C (i.e. a third server) and mount it on both servers and then load balance between them.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check that you can really read the files as user _www and that you can list them.

Maybe you're missing a diectory listing right for user _www. It's the execution right on directories for *Nix systems.

Answer (score 0):

What user did you run the mount command as? (note: I assume it's really mount_afp, not mount_hfs.)  That user will wind up "owning" the server connection, and will be the only one that gets authenticated access to the server files; other users on the AFP client computer will get the equivalent of guest access to server files.  You can view the connection ownership with the `mount` command:

```
$ mount
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
afp_0TQ55t0XgDP800dNMO0Pyetl-1.2d00000a on /Volumes/Public (afpfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by gordon)
```

From your description, it sounds like it should be working despite this (since the files are world-readable on server B)... but it still might be worth performing the mount under the _www user ID.

Comment: The _www user id can't log in an execute shell commands so I can't actually mount it as this user, and I would need some form ov crontab mainetence shoudl the mount disappear for whatever reason...

Comment: _www can't log in, but you can still execute the mount as _www with `sudo -u _www mount_afp ...`

Comment: Hmmm, ok, I'll look into that.